What is causing my view to resize when I press a button?
My iOS app has customizable user color settings. I made a view to be used for the color selection. The view has header buttons to pick between which color setting the user is changing and a grid of selectable color options.
Normal ColorSelector
When I press to switch between the selected color setting, the view resizes.
[Stretched ColorSelector after changing Color selection](https://i.sstatic.net/26nFPR5M.png
I cannot figure out what is causing this and am hoping an outside/more experienced perspective could catch it.
import SwiftUI

struct ColorSelect: View {
    
    //either 1 or 2 to represent which of the User's 2 colors is to be changed
    @State var colorSelection: Int = 1
    //Bool for the parent view
    @Binding var windowVisible: Bool
    //Color 1 Binding so parent view can update it's Colors
    @Binding var color1Link: Color
    //Color 2 Binding so parent view can update it's Colors
    @Binding var color2Link: Color

    //list of rgb values for displayed colors that is interpreted by func convertColor
    let colors = [144012063, //dark red
                  255049049, //red
                  255092000, //orange
                  255195000, //dark orange
                  255240031, //yellow
                  170255000, //dark green
                  057255020, //green
                  188237250, //very light blue
                  004217255, //blue
                  031081255, //dark blue
                  125018255, //dark purple
                  176038255, //purple
                  255016240, //pink
                  255189186, //peach
                  255255255, //white
                  170170170 //gray
                  ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //array for colorLinks
        var colorSlots = [color1Link, color2Link]
        //labels for User color setting selection buttons
        let col1Label = Text("Color 1")
            .font(.system(.title2,
                          design: .rounded))
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
        
        let col2Label = Text("Color 2")
            .font(.system(.title2,
                          design: .rounded))
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
        
        ZStack {
            //background visuals
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 34.0)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding(10)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30.0)
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                .padding(14)
            
            VStack {
                //User Color slot selection banner
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    //selected button will apply Color change to related User Color slot
                    Button {
                        colorSelection = 1
                    } label: {
                        if(colorSelection == 1) {
                            col1Label
                                .underline()
                        } else {
                            col1Label
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("|")
                        .font(.system(.title2,
                                      design: .rounded))
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button {
                        colorSelection = 2
                    } label: {
                        if(colorSelection == 2) {
                            col2Label
                                .underline()
                        } else {
                            col2Label
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                
                //4x4 Grid of color options
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(spacing: 5), 
                                    GridItem(spacing: 5), 
                                    GridItem(spacing: 5), 
                                    GridItem(spacing: 5)], spacing: 5) {
                    
                    ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                        
                        //actual Color object for rgb Int in array
                        let trueColor = convertColor(rgb: color)
                        //display for selectable color option
                        let buttonView = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                             .foregroundStyle(trueColor)
                                             .shadow(color: trueColor, radius: 7)
                        //determines if Color selection is User's selected Color
                        //    this has a separate issue where the User's Color
                        //    isn't updated because the change isn't read from defaults
                        @State var currColor = color == 
                                               UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: 
                                               "color\(colorSelection)rgb")
                        
                        //Display button if Color is not selected, else a view with check
                        if(!currColor) {
                            Button {
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(color,
                                                      forKey: "color\(colorSelection)rgb")
                                colorSlots[colorSelection - 1] = convertColor(rgb: color)
                            } label: {
                                buttonView
                            }
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        } else {
                            //makes selected color tile an inactive view with checkmark
                            ZStack {
                                buttonView
                                
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                    .padding()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(20)
            
            //'x' escape button in top right
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button {
                        windowVisible = false
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .shadow(color: .white,
                                    radius: 10)
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
    
    //takes the local Int interpretation of rgb and returns the associated Color object
    func convertColor(rgb: Int) -> Color {
        let b = Double(rgb % 1000) / 255
        let g = Double((rgb % 1000000) / 1000) / 255
        let r = Double((rgb % 1000000000) / 1000000) / 255
        
        return Color(red: r, green: g, blue: b)
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    ColorSelect(windowVisible: Binding.constant(true),
                color1Link: Binding.constant(.black),
                color2Link: Binding.constant(.black))
}

(There are other issues with my code like the actual picked Color for the color selection not updating since it is tied to UserDefaults and can't actually watch the change, but that's not what I'm focusing on right now)
To state the obvious, the view should not change size when switching between the Color Selection. I have tried putting it in a frame, but then it just shrinks in width in place of growing in height. I've tried removing spacers to see if they are somehow changing size when the state updates, but that didn't fix it either. I've stared at my Color 2 button action to follow any changes it makes, but still have not found any leads.

You shouldn't initialise a Binding with a value.  It should receive its value from the binding provided to the view initialiser.

Can you show how you are using this view?  I put your view into an app and it didn't change its size when I selected a colour.

I only initialized them for the sake of quickly converting my code to an example. The window changes size when you try to switch from Color 1 to Color 2, not when you select an actual color. I couldn't find a good way to communicate that.

Ok.  Again, that doesn't happen for me.  You probably need to go through some of Apple's tutorials on SwiftUI. There are a lot of issues with your code.  You shouldn't be declaring variables inside view bodies.  You can use the @AppStorage wrapper to get a value that is bound to user defaults.

I see, I thought I had already edited out the @Binding declarations at the beginning but I guess not. I will do so. As for reproducing the error, I've pasted this block of code into its own project and every time I press 'Color 2' for the first time after refreshing the view, the view size changes. Do you know why that would happen in one environment and not another?

I can't say without a [mcve].  I have refactored your code here - In SwiftUI you should try and keep views simple, ideally the code should fit on one screen.  I have also removed your re-invention of picker view; Try and use system controls where possible. Apple users expect consistency in UI.  Also, tag your platform. You mention "Window", so if you are running on macOS, provide this information.

The resizing problem you described isn't happening on my end when I run the app simulator, however, it does happen occasionally in the preview. I suspect that the preview may be loading differently than when it runs as an app, thus I wouldn't worry about it.
As for the UserDefaults bug, you can use @AppStorage properties to fix this. For example, this code will instantly update the selected color:
struct ColorSelect: View {
    @AppStorage("color1rgb") var color1Selection: Int = -1
    @AppStorage("color2rgb") var color2Selection: Int = -1
    /* other variables... */

    var body: some View {
        /* rest of the view... */
        ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
            let currColor = colorSelection == 1 ?
                            color == color1Selection :
                            color == color2Selection
        }
        /* rest of the view... */
    }
}

I would also recommend using an enum instead of an array for your "magic" color values, which would make more legible and self-documenting code:
enum SelectableColor: UInt32, CaseIterable {
    case DarkRed = 144012063
    case Red = 255049049
    case Orange = 255092000
    case DarkOrange = 255195000
    case Yellow = 255240031
    case DarkGreen = 170255000
    case Green = 057255020
    case VeryLightBlue = 188237250
    case Blue = 004217255
    case DarkBlue = 031081255
    case DarkPurple = 125018255
    case Purple = 176038255
    case Pink = 255016240
    case Peach = 255189186
    case White = 255255255
    case Gray = 170170170
}

extension SelectableColor {
    func toColor() -> Color {
        let b = Double(self.rawValue % 1000) / 255
        let g = Double(self.rawValue / 1000 % 1000) / 255
        let r = Double(self.rawValue / 1000000 % 1000) / 255
        
        return Color(red: r, green: g, blue: b)
    }
}

and in your view, you can do this:
ForEach(SelectableColor.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { selectableColor in
    let color = Int(selectableColor.rawValue)
                        
    //actual Color object for rgb Int in array
    let trueColor = selectableColor.toColor()
}

